# C-Compiler warning "Warning: too many arguments for format" how to fix?

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, mingw, compiler-warnings

I am just starting C programming and am using Eclipse Mars environment and MinGW compiler. I encountered a problem when writing a program that adds two integers and outputs the sum.

I received the "warning:too many arguments for format" dialog for the following statement:

```
printf("Sum of %d ", integer1," and %d", integer2," is: %d\n", sum);
```

Can anyone please explain why this is incorrect and how I may correct it?

(the full program is given below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(){

    int integer1; 
    int integer2;

    printf("Enter first integer \n"); 
    scanf("%d\n", &integer1);

    printf("Enter second integer \n"); 
    scanf("%d", &integer2); 

    int sum; 
    sum = integer1 + integer2;

    printf("Sum of %d ", integer1," and %d\a", integer2," is: %d\n", sum);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain how to rewrite the incorrect statement?

Comment: That's not how you use printf

Comment: "`printf("Sum of %d ", integer1," and %d\a", integer2," is: %d\n", sum);`" `printf` doesn't care about format specifiers in its _variadic_ args.

Comment: Can printf be used in a way where you can insert more than one argument? such as in Java where you just insert the addition symbol between arguments?

Comment: @AntonyNepgen May be [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) helps.

Comment: I know the `printf` man-pages is huge. But still, just read it. Learning C by Trial&Error could make you depressive.

Answer (score 4):

[`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
 takes **one** string that may include format specifiers, and then a list of arguments:

```
printf("Sum of %d and %d\a is: %d\n", integer1, integer2, sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `printf` has the following declaration

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

Thus you should write

```
printf("Sum of %d and %d\a is: %d\n", integer1, integer2, sum);
```